# Perl: Read columns and convert to array

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, trying to read a file with columns and creating an array.
I am having a file with following columns.

```
file.txt
A    15
A    20
A    33 
B    20 
B    45
C    32
C    78
```

I wanted to create an array for each unique item present in A with its values assigned from second column.
eg:

```
@A = (15,20,33)
@B = (20,45)
@C = (32,78)
```

Tried following code, only for printing 2 columns

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my %seen;
while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @elements = split (" ", $line);
    my $row_name = join "\t", @elements[0,1];
    print $row_name . "\n" if ! $seen{$row_name}++;

}
close FILE;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly some general Perl advice. These days, we like to use lexical variables as filehandles and pass three arguments to `open()`.

```
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
```

And then...

```
while (<$fh>) { ... }
```

But, given that you have your filename in `$ARGV[0]`, another tip is to use an empty file input operator (`<>`) which will return data from the files named in `@ARGV` without you having to open them. So you can remove your `open()` line completely and replace the `while` with:

```
while (<>) { ... }
```

Second piece of advice - don't store this data in individual arrays. Far better to store it in a more complex data structure. I'd suggest a hash where the key is the letter and the value is an array containing all of the numbers matching that letter. This is surprisingly easy to build:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %data; # I'd give this a better name if I knew what your data was

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($letter, $number) = split; # splits $_ on whitespace by default
  push @{ $data{$letter} }, $number;
}

# Walk the hash to see what we've got
for (sort keys %data) {
  say "$_ : @{ $data{$_ } }";
}
```

Comment: Storing data by a name in the data is called symbolic referencing, in case you want to research it. This is bad because the wrong name in the data could clobber a Perl variable. Using a hash with the name as a key is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to be something like:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>)
{
    chomp($line);
    my @elements = split (" ", $line);
    push(@{$seen{$elements[0]}}, $elements[1]);
}
```

This will create/append a list of each item as it is found, and result in a hash where the keys are the left items, and the values are lists of the right items. You can then process or reassign the values as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Nick,
How can i store or print this hash value to verify whether its taking only unique values from column 1 and respective values from column 2.

Comment: @DanishSheikh [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is the typical method, it uses references so something like `print Dumper \%seen;`